# How do malicious/scam websites match your obscure search entries on Google?

Tags: google-chrome, security, html, javascript, google-search

I was just checking out a piece of Python code when I searched for "from turtle import right, left, forward, speed, exitonclick, hideturtle" on [Google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=from%20turtle%20import%20right%2C%20left%2C%20forward%2C%20speed%2C%20exitonclick%2C%20hideturtle)

Without looking further I just clicked on the first search result that showed up--which turns out to be a scam site with stubborn JavaScript pop-ups and scared me quite a bit [with a creepy robot narrator alarm] and I had to kill Chrome in task manager. (I felt better after reading a [related post](https://superuser.com/questions/639084/malicious-confirm-navigation-dialogs))

The scam site looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnbAV.png) (need help inline the image...)

I don't think it's a coincidence that budgetinsurance.com happens to have the piece of Python code I'm looking for...so how on earth are these sites able to grab my search entry, insert it into their HTML documents and lure me in?

Comment: I don't see that first result here ...

Comment: I don't see it either.  looks like you've got an ad injecting infection of some kind.

Comment: That is strange (maybe it's limited to certain ISP?); I did the same search with IE, Firefox, as well as on my iPad and iPhone (safari) and got [the same thing](http://imgur.com/irZCv92)

Comment: Nope, not visible here either.